# ITHit Webdav Server - unable to copy files to mapped drive

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I've got the ITHit Webdav server set up on our web application, and it works from the website, and the java browser. When I map a drive to it through windows, and try to copy a file, it comes back with an error "Can't read from source file or disk." The file is in the operating system, and you can open and view it where it's being uploaded to, but when the copy fails, it will then erase the file.

Everything else appears to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Windows Shell for mapping the drive, which in turn using Microsoft Mini-redirector driver behind the scenes. Here are a couple of recommendations:

1. Make sure you have installed Windows updates and Microsoft Office updates (if you have it on this machine). Some of these updates influence Mini-redirector and fix issues with it.
2. Examine your WebDAV Server log. By default it is in \App_Data\WebDAV\Log\WebDAVLog.txt. Are there any exceptions in it?

You may also be interested in this article: [Connecting to WebDAV server on Microsoft Windows](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/windows/miniredirector)